# Can't install Scipy through pip

Tags: python, scipy

When installing scipy through pip with :

```
pip install scipy
```

Pip fails to build scipy and throws the following error:

```
Cleaning up...
Command /Users/administrator/dev/KaggleAux/env/bin/python2.7 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/Users/administrator/dev/KaggleAux/env/build/scipy/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/zl/7698ng4d4nxd49q1845jd9340000gn/T/pip-eO8gua-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/administrator/dev/KaggleAux/env/bin/../include/site/python2.7 failed with error code 1 in /Users/administrator/dev/KaggleAux/env/build/scipy
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/administrator/.pip/pip.log
```

How can I get scipy to build successfully? This may be a new issue with OSX Yosemite since I just upgraded and haven't had issues installing scipy before.

---

Debug log:

```
Cleaning up...
  Removing temporary dir /Users/administrator/dev/KaggleAux/env/build...
Command /Users/administrator/dev/KaggleAux/env/bin/python2.7 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/Users/administrator/dev/KaggleAux/env/build/scipy/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/zl/7698ng4d4nxd49q1845jd9340000gn/T/pip-eO8gua-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/administrator/dev/KaggleAux/env/bin/../include/site/python2.7 failed with error code 1 in /Users/administrator/dev/KaggleAux/env/build/scipy
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/administrator/dev/KaggleAux/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Users/administrator/dev/KaggleAux/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 283, in run
    requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options, root=options.root_path)
  File "/Users/administrator/dev/KaggleAux/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 1435, in install
    requirement.install(install_options, global_options, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/administrator/dev/KaggleAux/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 706, in install
    cwd=self.source_dir, filter_stdout=self._filter_install, show_stdout=False)
  File "/Users/administrator/dev/KaggleAux/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/util.py", line 697, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
InstallationError: Command /Users/administrator/dev/KaggleAux/env/bin/python2.7 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/Users/administrator/dev/KaggleAux/env/build/scipy/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/zl/7698ng4d4nxd49q1845jd9340000gn/T/pip-eO8gua-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/administrator/dev/KaggleAux/env/bin/../include/site/python2.7 failed with error code 1 in /Users/administrator/dev/KaggleAux/env/build/scipy
```

Comment: Try using 'sudo pip install scipy'

Comment: @PiotrDabkowski I installed python through homebrew so I shouldn't need to use sudo. Also, why would sudo help in the build step? I can see using it if it threw permission denied or something.

Comment: Are you sure the error is not caused by some permission problem?

Comment: Windows users can see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517129/how-do-i-install-scipy-on-64-bit-windows/40275240#40275240)

Comment: For Centos ensure u have lapack-devel if not do yum install lapack-devel

Answer (score 134, accepted):

After opening up an [issue](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/4102) with the SciPy team, we found that you need to upgrade pip with:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

And in `Python 3` this works:

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

for SciPy to install properly. Why? Because:

> Older versions of pip have to be told to use wheels, IIRC with --use-wheel. Or you can upgrade pip itself, then it should pick up the wheels.

Upgrading pip solves the issue, but you might be able to just use the `--use-wheel` flag as well.

Comment: This worked for me -- but I also had to install Luke's suggested packages `sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev gfortran`

Comment: I had to remove the old version of pip before upgrading. Then it worked perfectly.

Comment: Also, on my perfectly fresh 14.04 install, I also had to `sudo apt-get install python-dev`

Comment: I was having a lot of pip package errors when doing the installation. Upgrading pip resolved all the errors.

Answer (score 92):

Microsoft Windows users of 64 bit Python installations will need to download the 64 bit `.whl` of Scipy from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy), then simply `cd` into the folder you've downloaded the `.whl` file and run:

```
pip install scipy-0.16.1-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl
```

Comment: `scipy-0.16.1-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`

Comment: @gugol Perhaps you already tried this but you have to make sure the numbers after cp match your python version(e.g. cp34 = 3.4) and the amd64/win32 is correct.

Comment: `D:\TEMP>pip install "scipy-0.19.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl"
Requirement 'scipy\u20110.19.1\u2011cp35\u2011cp35m\u2011win_amd64.whl' looks li
ke a filename, but the file does not exist
scipy\u20110.19.1\u2011cp35\u2011cp35m\u2011win_amd64.whl is not a valid wheel f
ilename.

D:\TEMP>pip install "test.whl"
test.whl is not a valid wheel filename.

D:\TEMP>pip install test.whl
test.whl is not a valid wheel filename.` I cd to the directory try to run it then get an error,. Then I change the filename try to run it get another error. Method doesnt work...

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue as @user32882. What is it that we are doing wrong?

Comment: @gugol I had the same problem, the note from @Cyclotron3x3 helped me out; the `-cp27` in the file name refers to the version of python, I had to find the file with `-cp36` in the file name to match with my version of Python: 3.6.

Answer (score 68):

I face same problem when install Scipy under ubuntu. 
 I had to use command:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev gfortran
$ sudo pip3 install scipy
```

You can get more details here [Installing SciPy with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213551/installing-scipy-with-pip) 
Sorry don't know how to do it under OS X Yosemite.

Comment: This solved the problem I had using "Bash on Ubuntu on Windows 10".

Answer (score 41):

In windows 10, most options will not work. Follow these steps:

> In Windows 10 with CMD, you cannot download `scipy` directly using most of the well known commands like `wget`, `cloning scipy github`, `pip install scipy`, etc
>
> To install, go to [pythonlibs .whl files](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/) , and if you are using `python 2.7 32 bit` then download `numpy-1.11.2rc1+mkl-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl and scipy-0.18.1-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl` or if `python 2.7 62 bit` then download `numpy-1.11.2rc1+mkl-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl and scipy-0.18.1-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl`
>
> After downloading,save the files under your `python directory` , in my case it was `c:\>python27`
>
> Then run:

```
pip install C:\Python27\numpy-1.11.2rc1+mkl-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl 
pip install C:\Python27\scipy-0.18.1-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl
```

Note:

1. `scipy` needs `numpy` as dependency, so that's why we are downloading `numpy` before `scipy`.
2. `cp27` in .whl files means that these files are meant for `python 2.7` and `cp33` stands for `python 3.x` speciafically >=3.3

Comment: This worked for me on win 10 with Python 3.5 and 64b machine
pip install numpy-1.13.1+mkl-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
pip install numpy-1.13.1+mkl-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl

Comment: This answer solved the problem in my case (Windows 8.1), but I also needed to download and install [numpy+mkl](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy) wheel. Do this if you get an ImportError "NUMPY_MKL" when trying to import scipy after following this answer. Credits to [@VMAtm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37267399/importerror-cannot-import-name-numpy-mkl#answer-37281256).

Comment: For Python 3.6.2 on Windows 10 use `scipy-0.19.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl`

Comment: Thanks!, to use imread i was needed to install Pillow also
--pip install Pillow

Comment: For newer versions you need to install both `numpy` and `mkl` before scipy

Answer (score 13):

After finding [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14821297/scipy-build-install-mac-osx) for some clues, I got this working by doing

```
brew install gcc 
pip install scipy
```

(The first of these steps took 96 minutes on my 2011 Mac Book Air so I hope you're not in a hurry!)

Comment: I was actually unable to `brew install gcc`. It ended up throwing a bunch of errors. But after working with the Scipy guys; I found a solution. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: This actually turned out to be the straight forward solution for me. End up not building and installing downloaded scipy kit. :)

Comment: This worked for me, and it only took a few seconds for the first step

Answer (score 9):

If you are totally new to python read step by step or go directly to last step.
Follow the below method to install scipy 0.18.1 on Windows 64-bit , Python 64-bit .
If below command is not working then proceed further

```
pip install scipy
```

Be careful with the versions of

1. Python
2. Windows
3. .whl version of numpy and scipy files
4. First install numpy and scipy.

   ```
   pip install FileName.whl
   ```
5. For Numpy:http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy
   For Scipy:http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy

Be aware of the file name (check the version number).

Ex :scipy-0.18.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl

To check which version is supported by your pip, go to point No 2 below.

If you are using .whl file . Following errors are likely to occur .

> 1. You are using pip version 7.1.0, however version 8.1.2 is available.

You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command

> 2. scipy-0.15.1-cp33-none-win_amd64.whl.whl is not supported wheel on this platform

For the above error: start Python and type :

```
import pip
print(pip.pep425tags.get_supported())
```

Output:

> [('cp35', 'cp35m', 'win_amd64'), ('cp35', 'none', 'win_amd64'), ('py3', 'none', 'win_amd64'), ('cp35', 'none', 'any'), ('cp3', 'none', 'any'), ('py35', 'none', 'any'), ('py3', 'none', 'any'), ('py34', 'none', 'any'), ('py33', 'none', 'any'), ('py32', 'none', 'any'), ('py31', 'none', 'any'), ('py30', 'none', 'any')]

In the output you will observe cp35 is there , so download cp35 for numpy as well as scipy.Further edits are most welcome.

Answer (score 9):

For **Windows 10**

- Download **whl** file for the apropriate python version from
  **http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy**
- put it under directory  run the below command

> C:\directory> pip install scipy-0.19.0rc2-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl

Answer (score 6):

Rather than going the harder route of downloading specific packages. I prefer to go the faster route of using Conda. pip has its issues.

- Python -v (3.6.0)
- Windows 10 (64 bit)

> Conda , install conda from : https://conda.io/docs/install/quick.html#windows-miniconda-install

### command prompt

```
C:\Users\xyz>conda install -c anaconda scipy=0.18.1
Fetching package metadata .............
Solving package specifications:
```

Package plan for installation in environment C:\Users\xyz\Miniconda3:

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

```
mkl:       2017.0.1-0         anaconda
numpy:     1.12.0-py36_0      anaconda
scipy:     0.18.1-np112py36_1 anaconda
```

The following packages will be SUPERCEDED by a higher-priority channel:

```
conda:     4.3.11-py36_0               --> 4.3.11-py36_0 anaconda
conda-env: 2.6.0-0                     --> 2.6.0-0       anaconda
```

Proceed ([y]/n)? y

```
conda-env-2.6. 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00  32.92 kB/s
mkl-2017.0.1-0 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:24   5.45 MB/s
numpy-1.12.0-p 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00   5.09 MB/s
scipy-0.18.1-n 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:02   5.59 MB/s
conda-4.3.11-p 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00   4.70 MB/s
```

Answer (score 5):

1. Download SciPy from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy
2. Go into the directory the downloaded file is in and `pip install` the file.
3. Go to python shell, run `import scipy`; it worked for me with no errors.

Answer (score 5):

This is an alternative to **pip**.
I also had the same error when installing **scipy** with pip.

Then I downloaded and installed [MiniConda](http://conda.pydata.org/miniconda.html). And then I used the below command to install pytables.

```
conda install -c conda-forge scipy
```

Please refer the below screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

the best method I could suggest is this

1. Download the wheel file from this location for your version of python

   - https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scipy
2. Move the file to your Main Drive eg C:>
3. Run Cmd and enter the following

   - pip install scipy-1.0.0rc1-cp36-none-win_amd64.whl

Please note this is the version I am using for my pyhton 3.6.2 it should install fine

you may want to run this command after to make sure all your python add ons are up to date

```
pip list --outdated
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, manually download and execute
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs 
Scipy version suitable for you. Consider your Python version (python --version) **and your system architecture (32/64 bit)**. Choose the Scipy version accordingly.
scipy-0.18.1-**cp27**-cp27m-**win32** - for Python 2.7 32 bit
scipy-0.18.1-**cp27**-cp27m-**win_amd64** - for Python 2.7 64 bit
Otherwise the error 
**scipy-0.15.1-cp33-none-win_amd64.whl.whl is not supported wheel on this platform**
will popup on installation.

Now change directory to the downloaded file and execute command
`pip install scipy-0.15.1-cp33-none-win_amd64.whl.whl` (change file name appropriately)

I have added this answer only because the Arun's answer(found useful by myself) has not mentioned anything about 32/64 bit matching which i have faced.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue, and I had succeeded using `sudo`.

```
$ sudo pip install scipy
```

Answer (score 1):

I experienced similar issues with Python 3.7 (3.7.0b4). This was due to some changes regarding some encoding [assumptions (Python 3.6 >> Python 3.7)](https://docs.python.org/3.7/whatsnew/3.7.html)

As a result lots of package installations (e.g. via pip) failed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CentOS you need to install lapack-devel like so:

```
 $ yum install lapack-devel
```

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading the scipy file from the below link

https://sourceforge.net/projects/scipy/?source=typ_redirect

It will be a .exe file and you just need to run it. But be sure to chose the scipy version corresponding to your python version.

When the scipy.exe file is run it will locate the python directory and will be installed .

Answer (score 0):

use the wheel file to install
download from here
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy
install

```
pip install c:\jjjj\ggg\fdadf.whl
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is in the following steps: Fixing scipy for python [ 2.n < python < 3.n ]

Download the necessary files from: [http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/)

Download the version of numpy+mkl (needed to run scipy) and then download scipy for your python type (2.n python written as 2n) or (3.n python written as 3n), n is a variable. Note you must know whether you have a 32bit or 64bit processor.

Create a directory somewhere on your computer, example [C:\DIRECTORY] to install the files numpy+mkd.whl and scipy.whl

Once both file are downloaded, find the location of the file on your computer and move it to the directory you created.

> Example: First file installation is needed for scipy is in
>
> **C:\DIRECTORY\numpy\numpy-0.0.0+mkl-cp2n-cp2nm-win_amd32.whl**
>
> Example: Second file installation is in
>
> **C:\DIRECTORY\scipy\scipy-0.0.0-cp2n-cp2nm-win_amd32.whl**

Go to your command prompt and proceed the following example for a python version 2.n:

```
py -2.n -m pip install C:\DIRECTORY\numpy\numpy-0.0.0+mkl-cp2n-cp2nm-win_amd32.whl
```

should install

```
py -2.n -m pip install C:\DIRECTORY\scipy\scipy-0.0.0-cp2n-cp2nm-win_amd32.whl
```

should install

Test both modules on your python IDLE as following:

```
import numpy

import scipy
```

the modules are working if no errors are returned.

IFDAAS

Comment: Is this answer Windows specific, as the questioner is on OS X Yosemite?

Answer (score 0):

For windows(7 in my case):

1. download scipy-0.19.1-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl from 
                               http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy
2. create one some.bat file with content

   `@echo off
       C:\Python36\python.exe -m pip -V
       C:\Python36\python.exe -m pip install scipy-0.19.1-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl
       C:\Python36\python.exe -m pip list
       pause`
3. then run this batch file some.bat
4. call python shell
   "C:\Python36\pythonw.exe "C:\Python36\Lib\idlelib\idle.pyw"
   and test if scipy was installed with

import scipy

Comment: PS: I have multiple versions of Phyton(2.7,3.5 and 3.6) installed on same computer under windows 7

Answer (score 0):

You can test this answer:

```
python -m pip install --user numpy scipy matplotlib ipython jupyter pandas sympy nose
```