# Theano 0.8.2 not installing on Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, theano

I tried using

```
pip install Theano
```

but I get this error:

```
failed with error code 1 in ...\scipy\
```

ok this next then:

```
pip install scipy
```

same error...

how to install scipy...

[Can't install Scipy through pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26575587/cant-install-scipy-through-pip)

```
     Microsoft Windows users of 64 bit Python installations will need to download the 64 bit .whl of Scipy from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy then simply cd into the folder you've downloaded the .whl file and run:

    pip install scipy-0.17.1-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl
```

then I get this error:

```
  scipy-0.17.1-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

now what do i do.

Comment: Probably the easiest way to install scipy, numpy, Theano, etc. on Windows is to grab the [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) python distribution. It already has scipy and numpy in it and is easier to install scientific packages with.

Comment: I downloaded and installed Anaconda 3. 

Still cant get anything to work

Comment: "can't get anything to work" is not very useful for giving advice.

Answer (score 0):

make sure the python version of the wheel file is the same as your python version

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32913081)