# pip install Scipy fails... lapack and numpy distutils missing

Tags: numpy, scipy, pip, distutils, lapack

Python 3.5 on Windows 7

Modules installed: Numpy (1.11.1), Pandas (0.18.1), Matplotlib (1.5.1)

Pip version: 8.1.2

I'm installing many of the standard packages, and was able to install the 3 packages above without problems. Scipy's installation is not working however. After some searching on the issue through the 2 links below, I upgraded pip to the newest version. This hasn't fixed the issue, and I'm a bit lost.

From what I can gather, I'm missing **lapack** and **numpy distutils** files. I'm not familiar with lapack, and I installed the latest numpy just today. Perhaps I need to reset some paths and directories?

---

2 links I used for trouble shooting:

[Python pip install fails: invalid command egg_info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11425106/python-pip-install-fails-invalid-command-egg-info)

[Can't install Scipy through pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26575587/cant-install-scipy-through-pip)

---

Apologies for posting such a huge block of code, but I thought it would be best to include everything the error gives me.

```
Collecting scipy
  Using cached scipy-0.17.1.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: scipy
  Running setup.py install for scipy ... error
    Complete output from command c:\users\jon\appdata\local\programs\python\pyth
on35-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Jon\\
AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-ugbb8uwx\\scipy\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(
tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'
))" install --record C:\Users\Jon\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uh3v7wvi-record\install
-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    lapack_opt_info:
    openblas_lapack_info:
      libraries openblas not found in ['c:\\users\\jon\\appdata\\local\\programs
\\python\\python35-32\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\jon\\appdata\\local\\programs\\
python\\python35-32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    lapack_mkl_info:
    mkl_info:
      libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in ['c:\\users\\jon\\appdata\\local\\pro
grams\\python\\python35-32\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\jon\\appdata\\local\\progr
ams\\python\\python35-32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    c:\users\jon\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\num
py\distutils\system_info.py:639: UserWarning: Specified path C:\projects\windows
-wheel-builder\atlas-builds\atlas-3.10.1-sse2-32\lib is invalid.
      warnings.warn('Specified path %s is invalid.' % d)
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_info:
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_info:
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    c:\users\jon\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\num
py\distutils\system_info.py:1548: UserWarning:
        Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
        the ATLAS environment variable.
      warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
    lapack_info:
      libraries lapack not found in ['c:\\users\\jon\\appdata\\local\\programs\\
python\\python35-32\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\jon\\appdata\\local\\programs\\py
thon\\python35-32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    c:\users\jon\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\num
py\distutils\system_info.py:1559: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
        the LAPACK environment variable.
      warnings.warn(LapackNotFoundError.__doc__)
    lapack_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

    c:\users\jon\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\num
py\distutils\system_info.py:1562: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
        the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
      warnings.warn(LapackSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)
      NOT AVAILABLE

    Running from scipy source directory.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Jon\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-ugbb8uwx\scipy\setup.py",
line 265, in <module>
        setup_package()
      File "C:\Users\Jon\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-ugbb8uwx\scipy\setup.py",
line 262, in setup_package
        setup(**metadata)
      File "c:\users\jon\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-pack
ages\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 135, in setup
        config = configuration()
      File "C:\Users\Jon\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-ugbb8uwx\scipy\setup.py",
line 182, in configuration
        config.add_subpackage('scipy')
      File "c:\users\jon\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-pack
ages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1003, in add_subpackage
        caller_level = 2)
      File "c:\users\jon\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-pack
ages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 972, in get_subpackage
        caller_level = caller_level + 1)
      File "c:\users\jon\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-pack
ages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 909, in _get_configuration_from_setup_p
y
        config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
      File "scipy\setup.py", line 15, in configuration
        config.add_subpackage('linalg')
      File "c:\users\jon\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-pack
ages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1003, in add_subpackage
        caller_level = 2)
      File "c:\users\jon\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-pack
ages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 972, in get_subpackage
        caller_level = caller_level + 1)
      File "c:\users\jon\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-pack
ages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 909, in _get_configuration_from_setup_p
y
        config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
      File "scipy\linalg\setup.py", line 20, in configuration
        raise NotFoundError('no lapack/blas resources found')
    numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: no lapack/blas resources found

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\users\jon\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\python.exe -u -c
 "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Jon\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pi
p-build-ugbb8uwx\\scipy\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(
__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\
Users\Jon\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uh3v7wvi-record\install-record.txt --single-ver
sion-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Jon\AppD
ata\Local\Temp\pip-build-ugbb8uwx\scipy\
```

Comment: Why would you want to install this on windows by yourself? Please please please use something like [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) or other alternatives. Blas/Lapack installation on Windows might be possible, but non-trivial. You will need a Fortran-compiler for example. Stick to anaconda and the install-process of all these libraries is as simple as ```conda install numpy pandas scipy matplotlib```. (One more trial of convincing you: i mostly use Linux and install a lot of stuff from sources; but even on linux i still use Anaconda).

Comment: @sascha Yep. You've converted me; Anaconda is pretty great!