# I'm getting a weird error when trying to install scipy

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy

I entered pip install scipy and everything was installing fine but then all of a sudden I got this.

```
----------------------------------------
Command "c:\python34\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\
\Users\\Excel\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-l8y3lnbi\\scipy\\setup.py';exec(c
ompile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), _
_file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Excel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-xefll6
8u-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" fail
ed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Excel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-l8y3lnbi\sci
py\
```

Any idea on how to get this up and running?  I am using Python 3.x.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't install Scipy through pip](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26575587/cant-install-scipy-through-pip)

Comment: No, this is not a duplicate of that.  Although, I did check out that link and it didn't help me resolve the problem.  Any ideas?  Anyone?  Thanks.

Comment: I think the problem here is that there are MANY dependencies for scipy to run.  I can't seem to get all these dependencies downloaded and installed so I can't get scipy to run.  Ugh.  Is there a way I can get all dependencies for scipy so I can make this work?  I'm using Windows 7, which I think is not friendly to Python.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here!

https://sourceforge.net/projects/scipy/files/scipy/0.16.1/

I downloaded this: 'scipy-0.16.1-win32-superpack-python3.4.exe'

After I ran it, everything in my project worked fine.