# Unable to install Scipy for python27

Tags: python-2.7, scipy

I am trying to install scipy for python 27 64 bit (windows 7 64bit). Using pip,easy_install and also downloaded the whl file from `http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy`
I installed numpy using pip with no problem. For scipy what i did was

```
pip install scipy
```

and this is the error i am receieving

```
C:\Windows\system32>pip install scipy                                           Collecting scipy                                                                  Using cached scipy-0.18.1.tar.gz                                              Installing collected packages: scipy                                              Running setup.py install for scipy ... error                                      Complete output from command c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\karthik\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-ki85xq\\scipy\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\karthik\appdata\local\temp\pip-ib7fvw-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:                                                                                                                         Note: if you need reliable uninstall behavior, then install                     with pip instead of using `setup.py install`:                                                                                                                     - `pip install .`       (from a git repo or downloaded source                                            release)                                               - `pip install scipy`   (last SciPy release on PyPI)                                                                                                                                                                                          lapack_opt_info:                                                                openblas_lapack_info:                                                             libraries openblas not found in ['c:\\python27\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\python27\\libs']                                                                             NOT AVAILABLE                                                                                                                                                 lapack_mkl_info:                                                                c:\python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:640: UserWarning: Specified path C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Composer XE/mkl/lib/intel64 is invalid.                                                                                warnings.warn('Specified path %s is invalid.' % d)                            c:\python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:640: UserWarning: Specified path C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Composer XE/compiler/lib/intel64 is invalid.                                                                           warnings.warn('Specified path %s is invalid.' % d)                            c:\python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:640: UserWarning: Specified path C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Composer XE/mkl/include is invalid.                                                                                    warnings.warn('Specified path %s is invalid.' % d)                              libraries mkl_lapack95_lp64,mkl_blas95_lp64,mkl_intel_lp64,mkl_intel_thread,mkl_core,libiomp5md,libifportmd not found in []                                     NOT AVAILABLE                                                                                                                                                 atlas_3_10_threads_info:                                                        Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS                                                             libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in c:\python27\lib                            libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\python27\lib                             libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\                                        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\                                         libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in c:\python27\libs                           libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\python27\libs                          <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>                     NOT AVAILABLE                                                                                                                                                 atlas_3_10_info:                                                                  libraries satlas,satlas not found in c:\python27\lib                            libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\python27\lib                             libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\                                        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\                                         libraries satlas,satlas not found in c:\python27\libs                           libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\python27\libs                          <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>                             NOT AVAILABLE                                                                                                                                                 atlas_threads_info:                                                             Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS                                                             libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in c:\python27\lib                  libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\python27\lib                             libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\                              libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\                                         libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in c:\python27\libs                 libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\python27\libs                          <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>                          NOT AVAILABLE                                                                                                                                                 atlas_info:                                                                       libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in c:\python27\lib                      libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\python27\lib                             libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\                                  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\                                         libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in c:\python27\libs                     libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\python27\libs                          <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>                                  NOT AVAILABLE                                                                                                                                                 c:\python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1533: UserWarning:                                                                                     Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.                 Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the                 numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting                   the ATLAS environment variable.                                               warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)                                     lapack_info:                                                                      libraries lapack not found in ['c:\\python27\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\python27\\libs']                                                                               NOT AVAILABLE                                                                                                                                                 c:\python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1544: UserWarning:                                                                                     Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.                     Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the                 numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting                  the LAPACK environment variable.                                              warnings.warn(LapackNotFoundError.__doc__)                                    lapack_src_info:                                                                  NOT AVAILABLE                                                                                                                                                 c:\python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1547: UserWarning:                                                                                     Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.                       Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the                   numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting              the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.                                          warnings.warn(LapackSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)                                   NOT AVAILABLE                                                                                                                                                 Running from scipy source directory.                                            Traceback (most recent call last):                                                File "<string>", line 1, in <module>                                            File "c:\users\karthik\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-ki85xq\scipy\setup.py", line 415, in <module>                                                                 setup_package()                                                               File "c:\users\karthik\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-ki85xq\scipy\setup.py", line 411, in setup_package                                                            setup(**metadata)                                                             File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 135, in setup                                                                                  config = configuration()                                                      File "c:\users\karthik\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-ki85xq\scipy\setup.py", line 335, in configuration                                                            config.add_subpackage('scipy')                                                File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1000, in add_subpackage                                                                   caller_level = 2)                                                             File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 969, in get_subpackage                                                                    caller_level = caller_level + 1)                                              File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 906, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py                                                  config = setup_module.configuration(*args)                                    File "scipy\setup.py", line 15, in configuration                                  config.add_subpackage('linalg')                                               File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1000, in add_subpackage                                                                   caller_level = 2)                                                             File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 969, in get_subpackage                                                                    caller_level = caller_level + 1)                                              File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 906, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py                                                  config = setup_module.configuration(*args)                                    File "scipy\linalg\setup.py", line 20, in configuration                           raise NotFoundError('no lapack/blas resources found')                       numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: no lapack/blas resources found                                                                                       ----------------------------------------                                    Command "c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\karthik\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-ki85xq\\scipy\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\karthik\appdata\local\temp\pip-ib7fvw-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\karthik\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-ki85xq\scipy\
```

please help me thank you

Comment: what version of pip are you using? you may need to upgrade pip, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26575587/cant-install-scipy-through-pip

Comment: It's already upto date. I checked

Comment: The error you are seeing is because you don't have BLAS/LAPACK. If that doesn't make any sense to you I highly recommend using a distribution like [anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) if you plan to do any sciency stuff with Python. It just makes lots of these problems go away.

Comment: Thanks, I just copied it to c\python27\lib\site\packages now its working fine. In anaconda do i need to install scipy,numpy packages separately like in python27 or will they be available i just need to import while i code.