# Error when installing scipy in PyCharm?

Tags: scipy, pycharm, sklearn-pandas

I get the following error when attempting to install scipy to PyCharm 3.2:

Collecting scipy
  Using cached scipy-0.19.0.zip
Installing collected packages: scipy
  Running setup.py install for scipy: started
    Running setup.py install for scipy: finished with status 'error'
    Complete output from command C:\Users\leigh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\leigh\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\scipy\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\leigh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-8kx0fj8t-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:

```
Note: if you need reliable uninstall behavior, then install
with pip instead of using `setup.py install`:

  - `pip install .`       (from a git repo or downloaded source
                           release)
  - `pip install scipy`   (last SciPy release on PyPI)
```

Does anyone know how to deal with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure, but you might find your solution in this stackoverflow thread: [Can't install Scipy through pip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26964891/7787649).
If your problem persists, assuming you're on Windows (10), you could try:

Clone library from Github.

```
git clone https://github.com/scipy/scipy.git
```

Using CMD, navigate to the scipy folder

```
cd C:\..(your path)..\scipy
```

Then install by

```
python setup.py install
```

Hope it works out for you!