# How can I change the pip version on Google AI Platform during the training?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, pip, google-ai-platform

The pip version that Google AI platform training uses is 20 something, but I need pip version 21 because packages cannot be installed on the older pip version. Where and how can I change the pip version Google AI platform during the training?

Update:
Screenshot of logs when Google AI platform tries to install packages with the wrong version of PIP(20 instead of 21.1.3)
[image]

Update#2:
Full logs of Google AI platform training
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1H3Add_BrtiSt3ajBzLILXfaBfsCuLZJz/view?usp=sharing

Comment: which packages cannot be installed with Pip 20?

Comment: scipy for example cannot be installed - it tries many versions from 1.7.3 to 0.19, but does not actually install the necessary one. This can be solved if pip version is 21.1.3, but I do not know how to update the pip version on google ai platform

Comment: I have not tried this, but you might be able to specify pip in requirements.txt with a minimum version declaration.

Comment: I tried to specify it in requirements.txt, but it did not affect anything. However, I might have specified it incorrectly

Comment: I am attaching the picture of logs when Google AI platforms tries to install packages for better understanding of the problem

Comment: Based upon the part of the logs you posted, I do not think you have a pip problem. Post the complete logs.

Comment: I have added the link with logs in JSON format in Google Drive. If you need anything else ask me please

Comment: Go thru your log and analyze each of the errors. The logs show 12 errors. Some are connection failed, which means there might be some services down. Perhaps try again tomorrow.

Comment: I will absolutely try, but I suppose that the problem lies within the pip version. I use the TensorFlow Object Detection API repository for image segmentation purposes, and when I ran the setup of the repository I got the exact problem of libraries not being able to load. The solution was to update pip to version 21.1.3 and it worked! However, I do not properly know how to update pip version on Google AI platform or even to add correctly pip version to requirements.txt

Comment: Did you review the errors in your log and correct each one before worrying about pip versions?

Comment: Yes, I did! At least, the solution fixed the errors that you could see in the logs related to installing dependencies. I got the solution from this stackoverflow article that says to update pip(115 votes) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26575587/cant-install-scipy-through-pip

Comment: That link is so old that it no longer applies today. The version of pip you are using is not the problem.

Comment: Hi @DiasMashikov, is your issue resolved by upgrading the pip version?

Comment: Prajna Raj I do not know how to update the pip version on Google AI Platform. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: How are you submitting the training job? Have you followed all the steps described in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/packaging-trainer#before_you_begin) for packaging a training application?
You can refer to this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/specifying-dependencies-python#specifying_dependencies_with_pip) to specify the pip version in your requirements.txt file.