# numpy error while installing ninja using pip

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to install scipy but run into an error when installing ninja. I have no idea what it means.

```
pip install ninja
```

Output:

```
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
     × Building wheel for ninja (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.   │ exit code: 1   ╰─> [56 lines of output]
      Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
      -- The C compiler identification is GNU 10.2.1
      -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
      -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
      -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
      -- Detecting C compile features
      -- Detecting C compile features - done
      -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 10.2.1
      -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
      -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
      -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
      -- Detecting CXX compile features
      -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
      -- Configuring done
      -- Generating done
      -- Build files have been written to: /tmp/pip-install-uqf_okg8/ninja_2e64af0719684abb933d58ab1744c650/_cmake_test_compile/build
      
      
      --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      -- Trying "Ninja" generator
      --------------------------------
      ---------------------------
      ----------------------
      -----------------
      ------------
      -------
      --
      --
      -------
      ------------
      -----------------
      ----------------------
      ---------------------------
      --------------------------------
      -- Trying "Ninja" generator - success
      --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/home/raspiparenting/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 363, in <module>
          main()
        File "/home/raspiparenting/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 345, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "/home/raspiparenting/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 261, in build_wheel
          return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-fr91240v/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 412, in build_wheel
          return self._build_with_temp_dir(['bdist_wheel'], '.whl',
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-fr91240v/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 397, in _build_with_temp_dir
          self.run_setup()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-fr91240v/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 335, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 32, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-fr91240v/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/skbuild/setuptools_wrap.py", line 637, in setup
          env = cmkr.configure(
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-fr91240v/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/skbuild/cmaker.py", line 295, in configure
          cmd.append(prefix + "_NumPy_INCLUDE_DIRS:PATH=" + np.get_include())
      AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'get_include'
      [end of output]
     note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.   ERROR: Failed building wheel for ninja ERROR: Could not build wheels for ninja, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Things I tried:

- update pip (`pip install --upgrade pip`, [Can't install Scipy through pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26575587/cant-install-scipy-through-pip))
- reinstall numpy

Comment: Why do you try to install ninja if you want to install scipy?

Comment: It's part of the scipy installation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can try to `pip` specific version of ninja(That was work for
   me.), if you didn't.
2. Downgrade your pip version `pip install pip==21.3.1`.You can see here all [PIP versions](https://pypi.org/project/pip/#history) are listed out there any try one by one If You don’t want to use 21.3.1. and by downgrading pip your error will be fixed.
3. You should update the `pyproject.toml`  and try
   again, it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks :), that's why I love Matlab