# How do I remove Python and all packages on Mac?

Tags: python

When I first began to use python I was completely unaware of how to go about installing it. Safe to say it is a complete mess on my mac now. I have been trying to install the latest scipy for python 2.7 only to learn of the horrible mistakes I have been making. After reading the [SciPy build/install Mac Osx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14821297/scipy-build-install-mac-osx) I know now that my machine's python directories and paths are probably completely messed up and which is why I can't seem to get anything to work. So I want to uninstall everything and start fresh with apple's version of python so that everything will be synced up. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: search for `python uni` in your computer you must see `uninstall python`

Comment: Some of your Mac OSX's built-in functionality depends on Python -- should you manage to uninstall it who knows what bits and pieces of the OS functionality you depend on will grievously break!  Rather, just as for any other part of the OS: save your own data &c to somewhere else for safety; reinstall the OS and update it to the latest sub-release.  This will give you a pristine Python (among other things) and you can start afresh with your new-found knowledge.

Comment: If you worry so much for having your system clean then your best option is to reinstall OS X as @Alex Martelli mentioned(it is a good rule to just do what he says). That said it wouldn't be so difficult to get a clean Python install without reinstalling the whole OS, but this is somewhat too broad for Stackoverflow as it depends on what you did too your system.